# Provided certificate is not a valid self signed. Please provide either a valid self-signed certificate or certificate chain in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, certificate, key, aws-certificate-manager

I have got a certificate containing [those 4 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXFW3.jpg) and I want to import this certificate to aws,First I converted the key using this command

```
openssl rsa -in FILENAME.key -out FILENAME.key.rsa
```

And then I copy past the content of the cer file and the key to aws but it shows this error

```
Provided certificate is not a valid self signed. Please provide either a valid self-signed certificate or certificate chain.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding this (the p7b file)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[certificate chain data]
-----END CERTIFICATE----
```

and then

```
openssl pkcs7 -in cert.p7b -print_certs -out out.certs
```